# cannot insert into mysql

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception

```
    String registeritQuery= "INSERT INTO explorer.usr_itinerary(itinerary_desc, latd, longd, owner_id, creation_date, visited_date,it_grp_name" + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(registeritQuery);

    pst.setString(1,it_Desc);
    pst.setBigDecimal(2,new BigDecimal(latd));
    pst.setBigDecimal(3,new BigDecimal(longd));
    pst.setInt(4,userid);
    pst.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    pst.setDate(6,java.sql.Date.valueOf(visitdate));
    pst.setString(7,Integer.toString(n));
    cnt = pst.executeUpdate();
```

Table columns :

```
    id(auto_increment)- int
    itinerary_desc  - varchar
    latd - decimal - (9,6)
    longd- decimal - (9,6)
    creation_date - date
    visited_date - date
    it_grp_name - varchar
```

I am getting all the values before preparedStatement, but it does not insert the record.

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at explorer.MySQLDataStoreUtilities.insertItinerary(MySQLDataStoreUtilities.java:182)
    at org.apache.jsp.insertItinerary_jsp._jspService(insertItinerary_jsp.java:122)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: is autocommit false ? Add the code with connection details

Comment: No, i am not getting any error. I am able to add the record manually using mysql workbench with same data I am providing to preparedStatement.

Comment: I don't see an ending parentheses in your insert statement. `name) + "VALUES ('   Most likely throwing an error because of this.

Comment: I changed the statement to: 
"INSERT INTO explorer.usr_itinerary(itinerary_desc, latd, longd, owner_id, creation_date, visited_date,it_grp_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

still not able to add the record.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have an empty catch block somewhere.  That's why you're getting no messages.

Comment: I have updated the question. It is getting error on: 
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(registeritQuery);

Comment: It turns out Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

even though all the privileges are yes.

Answer (score 2):

Your Query should be like this :

```
String registeritQuery= "INSERT INTO explorer.usr_itinerary(itinerary_desc, latd, longd, owner_id, creation_date, visited_date,it_grp_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

you missed the `) and space` 
your query is like this `it_grp_name"+"VALUES` this mean `it_grp_nameVALUES`

so you should to replace it to this `it_grp_name)"+" VALUES` this mean `it_grp_name) VALUES`

Comment: String registeritQuery= "INSERT INTO explorer.usr_itinerary(itinerary_desc, latd, longd, owner_id, creation_date, visited_date,it_grp_name) " + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

it is not working. I updated the statement like this.

Comment: No. code runs but there is not any error. 
owner_id is foreign key to another table, does it matter? I am not sure.

Comment: are you using `try{}catch(){}` or not

Comment: Why on earth would you create that query string by concatenation?  Just write it out without concatenation.